# Drawing priority of HTML elements defined via CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to prevent the web page rendering like this

1. Fill the whole background with #51a025
2. Tile images/bg.png
3. Tile content_bg.png

Those steps can be quite visibly distracting, and depending on the browser/machine can take a *while*

So my question is, "How can I prevent that effect?"

*The content is generated from php and mysql so I'm guessing the drawing is linked to the database interaction.*

Here's the CSS

```
body {
 font-size: 75.5%; /* Resets 1em to 10px */
 font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 background:#51a025 url('images/bg.png') repeat-x 0 0;
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 }

#page {
 background: url('images/content_bg.png') repeat-y 0 0;
 text-align: left;
 }
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the css nor the html.  given that you say the bg images are tiny, there's no reason your html or css could be causing this.  Unless more information is added, like a a code sample that reproduces the problem, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

How big are `bg.png` and `content_bg.png`?  If the files are large then the delay you're seeing is likely just how long they're taking to download.

You could maybe try [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or a similar tool to get the file size down.

Comment: I thought that too, but they're tiny

Comment: @Danny In that case, do you have a URL that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force one css rule to evaluate before another. Generally, they are evaluated in the order they are placed in the file/tag. CSS is really, really, really fast, even at it's slowest it loads faster than the human eye can detect. So my answer is ***you can't prevent this effect***, but it doesn't matter because CSS is super fast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, perhaps it not CSS thats the causing the slow drawing. I'm telling ya its undeniably noticeable...

Comment: @Danny I believe you. Perhaps it's the images? Could you edit your answer with a link to one of them?

Answer (score 0):

> The content is generated from php and
>   mysql so I'm guessing the drawing is
>   linked to the database interaction.

Nope, the content is generated server-side and delivered to your browser as HTML. The drawing is done purely by the browser (client-side).